# Trying to make an average word length from a txt file

Tags: python

```
file=open("apple.txt","r")
count=0
for line in file:
    words=line.split( )
    for character in words:
        for letter in character:
            letter=ord(letter)
            if letter<=95 and letter>=65:
                count+=1
            elif letter<=122 and letter>=97:
                count+=1
averagewordlength=count/len(words)
print(len(words))
```

FYI the apple.txt is

```
I ate apples.
How many apples did you eat.
```

these two sentences are on different lines.
The problem im having is that my len(words) is only counting the words from how many apples did you eat. So im wondering how I can make it so the len(words) counts all the lines in the file not just the very last one.

Comment: Don't put ASCII codes in your script. Python has built-in methods like `isalpha()` that will tell if a character is alphabetic.

Comment: In addition to using built-in functions that will allow you to decide if a charater is a letter, you may also need to consider things like "I didn't eat apples." The main problem with your code right now is that you use `len(words)` which is the number of words on the last line, but you want to use the total number of words (which would be the sum of all `len(words)` in your outer loop).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that in `len(words)`, `words` only refers to the words of the last line as its value is renewed at each iteration of the `for` loop.

On a sidenote, if it matters, here is a more direct way:

```
words_lengths = [len([x for x in word.upper() if x.isalpha()]) for line in file for word in line.split()]
averagewordlength = sum(words_lengths)/len(words_lengths)
```